# DTD to XML Errors

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

So I was designing an XML file based on a certain DTD. The logic is thus:

```
Category >> Books(can have many entries) >>Author[required], Price[required], Description, Image)
```

Here is the DTD generated:

```
<!ELEMENT CATAGORY (PRODUCT+)>
<!ELEMENT PRODUCT
(NAME,PRICE,DESCRIPTION*,PICTURE*)>
<!ATTLIST PRODUCT
NAME CDATA #REQUIRED
PRICE CDATA #REQUIRED
DESCRIPTION CDATA #IMPLIED
PICTURE CDATA #IMPLIED
CATEGORY (BOOKS|GADGETS|OTHERS) "BOOKS"
AUTHOR CDATA #REQUIRED
ISBN CDATA #IMPLIED
INVENTORY (InStock|Backordered|Discontinued) "InStock">
```

However, I am unable to write a valid XML. I wrote thus:

```
<CATAGORY>
    <PRODUCT NAME="XML BOOK" AUTHOR="XML GENIUS" CATEGORY="BOOKS" DESCRIPTION="BRILLIANT XML BOOK."  INVENTORY="InStock" ISBN="653725327" PRICE="36.99" PICTURE=""/>
    <PRODUCT NAME="XML MASTERS" AUTHOR="XML TEACHER" CATEGORY="BOOKS" DESCRIPTION="" INVENTORY="InStock" ISBN="" PICTURE="" PRICE="23.99"/> 
</CATAGORY>
```

I get the following error. Any help is appreciated.

```
Content model of element <PRODUCT> requires further child elements.
    Error location: CATAGORY / PRODUCT
    Details
        VC: Element Valid (2): Content model of element <PRODUCT> requires further child elements.
```

Comment: You haven't modeled the child elements `NAME`, `PRICE`, ...

Comment: @Boldewyn I am really new to XML, what do you mean by model? I want to keep them as simple as a single line of text, what do I need to add more? Thanks.

Comment: That means simply, that you said, `PRODUCT` needs a child `NAME`, but you've never defined something along `<!ELEMENT NAME (#PCDATA)>`.

Comment: Ah, I see. What you wrote for the `PRODUCT` element, `(NAME,PRICE,DESCRIPTION*,PICTURE*)`, says, that `<PRODUCT/>` has these as child _elements_, not as attributes. Try replacing that with `<!ELEMENT PRODUCT EMPTY>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of `PRODUCT`,

```
<!ELEMENT PRODUCT
    (NAME,PRICE,DESCRIPTION*,PICTURE*)>
```

says, that a `<PRODUCT>` must contain one `<NAME>` element, one `<PRICE>` element and so on. But from the `ATTLIST` and your example code you want to use attributes. So simply change the definition to

```
<!ELEMENT PRODUCT EMPTY>
```